# Dynamically add items to NavigationView with loading gif

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml, android-navigation

I have a Navigation View (sidebar) that looks like this:

[image]

The first 4 items in the list are static (they will never change). However, I need to dynamically add items to the sidebar (which are fetched from my REST API) below the divider in the picture above. A few questions:

1. How can I dynamically add new items to the sidebar under a new subheader, below the divider?
2. While it's adding the items, how can I display a loading (spinner) gif below the divider to notify the user that something is happening?

Here is the NavigationView from my activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    />
```

And here is my `menu_drawer` (with the static items):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_first"
            android:title="Inbox"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_second"
            android:title="Starred" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_third"
            android:title="Sent mail" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_fourth"
            android:title="Drafts" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: You can use listview inside navigation view

Answer (score 1):

*This answer uses the library [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer).*

As noted by @Ravi Gadipudi you can use the [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library.

As the [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) does not contain the feature of a loading progress by default i have modified the [DrawerActivity](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/DrawerActivity.java) of the [sample app](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/tree/develop/app) to feature and showcase what you try to achieve.

Here's the sample code creating a `Drawer` which is empty (just with the profile) by default, with a indeterminate `ProgressBar`. As soon as you click on the profile image (you can move this code to the position you need it) it will add some `DrawerItems` and the `ProgressBar` will hide.

```
public class DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //save our header or result
    private LinearLayout progressBarContainer;
    private AccountHeader headerResult = null;
    private Drawer result = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_dark_toolbar);

        // Handle Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Create a few sample profile
        // NOTE you have to define the loader logic too. See the CustomApplication for more details
        final IProfile profile = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Mike Penz").withEmail("mikepenz@gmail.com").withIcon("https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/1476232?v=3&s=460").withIdentifier(100);
        // Create the AccountHeader
        headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
                .addProfiles(
                        profile
                )
                .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean current) {
                        addDrawerItems();
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .build();

        //Create the drawer
        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withHasStableIds(true)
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult) //set the AccountHeader we created earlier for the header
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withShowDrawerOnFirstLaunch(true)
                .build();

        //THIS CODE WILL ADD THE PROGRESS TO THE DRAWER AND CENTER IT BELOW THE HEADER
        //Create the ProgressBar to display
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        //create the container which contains the progressBar and centers it
        progressBarContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
        progressBarContainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        //define the size for the progressBar
        int size = (int) com.mikepenz.materialize.util.UIUtils.convertDpToPixel(72, this);
        progressBarContainer.addView(progressBar, size, size);
        //add the padding to display the ProgressBar below the header (centered)
        progressBarContainer.setPadding(0, (int) (DrawerUIUtils.getOptimalDrawerWidth(this) * 9d / 16d), 0 , 0);
        //add the progressBarContainer to the layout
        result.getSlider().addView(progressBarContainer, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    public void addDrawerItems() {
        //HIDE THE PROGRESS
        progressBarContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //add the drawerItems as you need them
        result.addItems(
                new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_compact_header).withDescription(R.string.drawer_item_compact_header_desc).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_wb_sunny),
                new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_action_bar_drawer).withDescription(R.string.drawer_item_action_bar_drawer_desc).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home),
                new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_multi_drawer).withDescription(R.string.drawer_item_multi_drawer_desc).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_gamepad),
                new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_non_translucent_status_drawer).withDescription(R.string.drawer_item_non_translucent_status_drawer_desc).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_eye).withSelectable(false).withBadgeStyle(new BadgeStyle().withTextColor(Color.WHITE).withColorRes(R.color.md_red_700)),
                new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_advanced_drawer).withDescription(R.string.drawer_item_advanced_drawer_desc).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_adb),
                new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_keyboard_util_drawer).withDescription(R.string.drawer_item_keyboard_util_drawer_desc).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_style),
                new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_embedded_drawer).withDescription(R.string.drawer_item_embedded_drawer_desc).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_battery_charging_full),
                new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_fullscreen_drawer).withDescription(R.string.drawer_item_fullscreen_drawer_desc).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_style)
        ); // add the items we want to use with our Drawer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look into this library its a well built library for drawer https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer . or my suggestion is replace the menu with list view items and you can add/remove this to list view dynamically

Comment: I've looked into that library, but I found nothing on loading items dynamically nor how to display a loading gif.

Comment: I prefer you adding a custom drawer and adding your custom layout over there. look into this tutorial for adding custom layout. http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Comment: Add the GIF in your drawer layout

Comment: There has to be a way to do this with `NavigationView` and not a custom drawer...

Comment: Please post here. if you find out any solution.

Comment: @user5387210 you can add items dynamically without any issues. a loading gif is not supported by default but can be added without any big complications. The MaterialDrawer library does not use the NavigationView as it is to limited, and the MaterialDrawer provides a lot of additional functionality (including custom drawerItems, ...)